# ImportError with GeoDataFrame.from_file(..) shapefile load - Fiona issue

Tags: geopandas

I've installed Geopandas and its dependencies. An ImportError results in Fiona's ogrext.so lookup of "_CPLSetThreadLocalConfigOption":

**Code executed:**

```
boros = GeoDataFrame.from_file("./data/nybb_14a_av/nybb.shp")
```

**Error result:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ronaldbjork/Documents/Boundary Solutions/geopandaone.py", line 3, in <module>
    import fiona
  File "/Applications/scipy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fiona/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from fiona.collection import Collection, BytesCollection, vsi_path
  File "/Applications/scipy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site- packages/fiona/collection.py", line 7, in <module>
    from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/scipy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fiona/ogrext.so, 2): **Symbol not found: _CPLSetThreadLocalConfigOption**
  **Referenced from: /Applications/scipy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fiona/ogrext.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup**
```

Comment: If you use `conda install fiona`, it is a problem of Anaconda.

Comment: Should I use "pip install fiona" within Anaconda instead? Is it a version incompatibility. Or should I give-up on Anaconda and start with a new environment?

Comment: If you are on Mac OS X, install [Fiona-1.6.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl](https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/F/Fiona/Fiona-1.6.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=8c0896dbc72446e3919bec20dfae69c8) from the [Python Package Index (PyPI)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fiona/1.6.0)

Comment: I tried using this whl file. I'm getting this:
The directory '/Users/ronaldbjork/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Fiona-1.6.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: I tried -H flag: sudo -H pip install .....whl
Get the following:
Fiona-1.6.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Comment: In python:
>> distutils.util.get_platform()
'macosx-10.5-x86_64'
Do I need to set "_PYTHON_HOST_PLATFORM". It currently has no value.
My current version of Mac OSx is 10.9.5
My python version is 2.7.10

Comment: Reinstalling with pip appears to work. Apparently conda install resulted in the problem. Though I still wonder why whl install fails.
pip install Fiona==1.6.0  # works GeoPandaFrame.from_file(...shp) works

Comment: Apparently my problem was with conda. I reinstalled with pip and my code boros = GeoDataFrame.from_file("./data/nybb_14a_av/nybb.shp"). Now works.  Still interested to know what I'd need to do to make the whl installation work.

Comment: Generally, installers are made for the standard Apple Python (in /usr/bin/, look at [Python under Mac OS X:Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17760868/835653)) and modules installed in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. Anaconda is different

Answer (score 1):

The [IOOS](http://www.ioos.noaa.gov/) has a number of [packages](https://anaconda.org/IOOS) that look relevant for you.  You can create an environment with:

```
conda create -n my_gis_project python fiona geopandas  -c https://conda.anaconda.org/ioos
```

Creating an anaconda environment will keep you away from those "you don't have access" errors and keep the root environment clean.  One bad package or pip install into your root environment could have  adverse consequences down the road.